# How do I select the vertices inside these blue lines?

Tags: vertices

Sometimes whenever I import models blue outlines appear on specifics parts of the model. I wanted to know HOW can I select them individually?[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those blue outlines appear to be sharp edge marks. They are added to geometry to tell the renderer to not blend the normals over that edge when shading smooth. You can select areas bounded by them by doing the following:

1. Select a face somewhere inside the desired region.
2. Press Ctrl+L to Select Linked All.
3. Open the operator panel in the bottom right, and select the “Sharp” delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good chance to use the *Select* menu:

[image: Select menu showing select similar with Sharpness highlighted].

In edit mode, make sure you're in edge select mode (short cut *keyboard* <kbd>2</kbd>)

Deselect all (short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>)

Use the menu entry *Select → Select Similar → Sharpness*

You can then remove the sharpness mark by using the *Edge* popup menu (Shortcut Ctrl–E) and select *Clear Sharp*